# Why does this program output different answers when using floats vs. ints?

Tags: floating-point, int

I did a program that will find factorial of a number. But for the integer data type answer is up to 12 and for float, it's 13. But sizeof both integer and float are 32. Why am I seeing different answers?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i=1,fact=1;


    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(i<=n)
    {
        fact=fact*i;
        i=i+1;
    }
    printf("fact is %d\n",fact);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're two completely different number representations. There is no reason to expect them to be the same. They're giving different answers because they're totally different.

Arabic numbers can count up to 999 with three places. Roman numerals can't count past III. Why the difference? Well, because the two number systems are completely different ways of representing numbers and use the same amount of space in completely different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in that when you used floats, you didn't change the scanf and thus tried to read an integer representation into a floating point variable, as they are the same size it will fit but as David rightly points out they use the 32 bits in completely different ways.

If you read the value correctly into the Float the answer would have been the same.

You would also need to change the printf too.